# как установить Freeglut в ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, opengl, glut

Столкнулся с проблемой, как установить в ubuntu freeglut ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

надо в терминале запустить :

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev libglew-dev
```

и на всякий пожарный (хотя я так и не понял зачем)

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

так же в файле проекта надо  подключить библиотеки  `libOpenGL.so`, `libglut.so` :

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    getBMP.cpp

HEADERS += \
    getBMP.h

# --- linux ---
# хоть заголовочный и не вызывается все таки функции вызываются
unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lOpenGL #для freeglut

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lGLEW

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lglfw

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GLFW
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GLFW

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lglut #для freeglut

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL


unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lGLU

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
```

вот само подключение в `main.cpp` :

```
  #include <freeglut.h>
  ...
  // Основная рутина. Main routine.
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printInteraction();
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitContextVersion(4, 3); // ВОТ !!! функция freeglut 
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE); // ВОТ !!! функция freeglut 

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("texturedSphere.cpp");
    glutDisplayFunc(drawScene);
    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyInput);

    // ---
//    // Новые функции для регистрации
//    glutIgnoreKeyRepeat(1);
    glutSpecialUpFunc(releaseKey);

//    // OpenGL - инициализация функции теста
//    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    // ---

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    setup();

    glutMainLoop();

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `$ curl -s https://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz | zgrep ^Package: | wc -l` выдаёт 6391 пакет. как установить четыре из них, вы уже написали. осталось написать всего лишь про 6387 пакетов. ну а там подтянутся и другие репозитории: всякие там multiverse и прочие restricted. а потом настанет очередь других версий дистрибутива. солнце ещё высоко!

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin если не мы, то кто ваще? Гугель сам себя не наполнит!

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin у меня все ставится Убунту " механический бобёр". Увы эмулировать вашу ошибку не могу и посему и решить тоже.